# How to influence in a very process oriented, top down, environment?

Tags: work-environment, management, developer

I find it hard to adjust to the top down decision making from management where I work. One example: I have raised my interest in moving to a different team a handful times, but management sometimes forget to come back to me, or I just receive a short "no". I feel I don't have much influence, but in the end of the day I am writing the code so I wish I felt more ownership to the processes.

To narrow what is going on to the essencial: My managers mainly focus on how they can keep pace with processes they have initialized, and care less for the human factor.

To illustrate what arguments leads me to that conclusion. 1) We are understaffed on both my current team and the one I wish to transfer to. 2) Management have initialized a large project that soon will split my current team into two teams. In my view, they take a big risk taking on a big project on our team when they are informed I am interested in changing team.

What is the best way to influence in a work environment like this, where concerns for the process are more important than the concerns of the individual? How can I make the managers care more about my perspective, hopefully without end up being perceived as a negative or difficult employee?

Comment: This is broad because you're hitting multiple issues - retention issues, requesting a team move, having ownership of your own work product, cooperating with highly technical managers who are former high level independant contributors - any one of these areas is rich with great questions, but there's no clear concept in this post on exactly what you want to change about your environment.  I'd suggest editing to pull this into a single goal.

Comment: @bethlakshmi Thanks for your constructive feedback. I have updated my question, I hope this is better.

Comment: "they take a big risk taking on a big project on our team when they are informed I am interested in changing team."  They know you wish to change teams, but you've been denied.  You're not changing teams.  I don't really understand where you're coming from with this question.  Your managers are your managers.  It's not uncommon for them to have much more control/power than you.

Answer (score 3):

Influencing others is sometimes a difficult skill to learn.  It is possible, as Wesley Long believes, that there is no such opportunity in your organization.  It is also possible that there is such an opportunity.

In order to convince people of something, you need to understand their motivations.  The first thing I recommend you do is to understand the culture of the group that is making the policies.  Do they act on feeling?  On evidence?  On experience for things previously having gone wrong?  An attempt to become ISO5001 certified so they can better compete in your particular market?

Once you know to what they are reacting, you can re-evaluate your position.  There may be a very good reason for the policies that are being created, to which you are not yet privy.  You can also look at the issue that they are trying to address and see if there's a alternate solution, or if you can demonstrate that it's a non-issue.  Or, perhaps, you can demonstrate that the cure is worse than the problem.

Comment: Our middle management react based on what they know and gut feeling. If in doubt, stick with the plan. Better to decide something than nothing. They know the organization well and what is needed, but treat developers like external consultants with no influence. I know my managers well. I sometimes go to the head of the department, he is coming from outside so he has different view on things. But I think going past middle management over and over again is not a solution.

Comment: OK.  For the policies about which you disagree, why were each instituted?  Just because a plan was needed?  Or were they created to solve/prevent particular issues?

Comment: The issues management are focused on is how they can keep pace with processes they have initialized. That is the only reason I can think of why they won't let me change to the other team. To illustrate what arguments leads me to the conclusion. 1) We are understaffed on both teams. 2) Management have initialized a large project that soon will split my current team instead of bringing in consultants. I believe that processes are the controlling factor.

Comment: Have you tried asking any of them the reason for the policies?

Comment: Your question actually helped med gather my thoughts more, and I have updated my original question. I am bringing up my concern or wishes with management if I am not satisfied with the answers in the first round, yes. It varies how good answers I get even after second round. Sometimes I understand there are good reasons for a decision, but other times I just don't get any wiser.

Answer (score 0):

"...  but in the end of the day I am writing the code so I need some ownership to the processes."

No, you don't need it to do your work.  You may want it, but the process given to you is what you have to work within.

"Ownership of Process" is a strange concept.  Are you using it euphemistically to mean "Authority over the process?"  I believe you mean either you want influence on processes, or at least some latitude within them for your own work.  In a traditional engineering world, a change in process would require doing a cost/benefit analysis and a risk mitigation analysis (at the very least), then proposing it for review by management.  Software development "borrows" a lot from engineering, but it doesn't bring all of it.  It sounds to me like middle management is trying to bring some process control aboard, too.  If you need the "fast and loose" feel you had before, you may be in trouble.

It seems this organization is designed to specifically prevent you from having influence.  Without a major management restructuring (which you have no ability to initiate), things will not change.

If you mean "ownership" of the code, as I originally thought you meant, then that's never going to happen.  Your code is work product, and it belongs to your employer as soon as you type it.

If you need "ownership" for your own personal sense of job satisfaction, then you definitely want to find a different organization.  Keep in mind, though, that anything you write as an employee or as a contractor under a "work for hire" agreement is not now and never was yours, no matter what you "feel."

Comment: I have been thinking about going to a smaller shop because maybe my views would be more appreciated there.

Comment: @arg1torokca1 - You should probably pursue that.  It would probably make you much happier in the long run.  Life is too short to work where you're not happy.

Comment: You have a good point here. Actually that was what the senior colleague did in our case.

Comment: @arg1torokca1 - if they're more interested in process than outcomes other people in your shop are probably eyeing the exits.  Go fish, and see if anything bites.

Comment: @MeredithPoor - The management is not ignorant about outcome, but the process have too often been more important than the concerns of the individual. I am starting to think that the situation will not improve, so I understand I have to be open for other opportunities. I appreciate your feedback, it helps me see things more clearly.

Comment: Hi Wesley, by ownership, the asker is referring to ownership of the *process* not the *product*. I suggest you [edit] your answer so it addresses how the op might influence the work environment so that employees are empowered to make more of their own decisions. Note that on answers that [suggest a person quit their job](http://goo.gl/2XoAV), we require those answers include facts, references, or experiences that happened to you personally as per [the back it up rule](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123/should-we-add-a-back-it-up-rule-to-the-faq-now).

Comment: As an aside, please don't use answers or edits for personal attacks or to even address other users. I edited it out, as that won't be tolerated on our site.

Comment: @jmort253 - I believe I addressed the process issue in paragraph 3.  Also, I suggested a different organization, not quitting his job.  If that can mean another team or even division within the same company, I believe the OP would be much happier.  It is the process he is unhappy with.  I addressed his "ownership" concerns separately from his "process" concerns.

Comment: Hi Wesley, I guess what confuses me is how in that paragraph you mention that code you write is not yours. That makes me think you're referring to ownership not process. If these aren't clear to me they likely aren't clear to others as well. Hope these suggestions are helpful! :)

Comment: OK, I see where you're coming from.  I must be relying too much on my personal experience.  When I've had subordinates say they needed "Ownership" of anything, it's been because they just figured out that they don't own the work product.  "Ownership of Process" is a very strange concept, as in the consulting world processes are considered Intellectual Property, but I'll go with it.  Let me see what I can do.

Comment: By ownership to the process I was thinking about influence in how to get from input to output, not ownership in anything that could be considered intellectual property in our book. We have theoretically a lot of freedom in how we deliver a solution for our customers. But in practice we have practical and some artificial restrictions on the hows and whats. The artificial restrictions bothers me a bit thought.